# Photo Competition 2021-09-06: Relationships

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Relationships

A photo which shows a two (or more) people sharing moment. Like Mom-kids, Father-kids, Siblings, Person-pet, Person-Teacher.

This theme was suggested by [Sudarshan Kadam](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/9677/sudarshan-kadam).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/126078/photo-competition-2021-09-06-relationships?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on September 20, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Comment: We should have users put in what mode they shot the picture in. P, A, S, M What do you think?

Comment: @JcbJoe it doesn't really matter _how_ the exposure was achieve, through full-manual, priority, or full-program. The exposure is the exposure.

Comment: @JcbJoe but that's just my opinion. [Add your suggestion as an answer to the Meta question about the photo contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7109/new-photo-contest), so others can up/downvote it and comment on it specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @scottbb

Comment: @scottbb Did you forget to close the voting on this one?

Comment: @MichaelC Oops, you're right. I accepted the highest vote, but forgot to lock it. Done. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unknown couple at town fair in Laurel, MD
Shot with Olympus EP-3 (lens 14-42)
1/200, F8. iso 200

[image: affection never dies]

Answer (score 17):

### Bicycle Brothers

[image: Bicycle Brothers]

A pair of brothers out for a ride along the East River Greenway on a cool spring afternoon in Manhattan - April 16, 2016

Nikon D700; Nikkor 80-400; 2X Teleconverter; ISO 200 1/1600 f/5.6 800mm

Answer (score 14):

### Lounging in the park

[image]

A couple lounging in Central Park on a warm New York afternoon - July 3, 2015

Nikon D700; Nikkor 80-400; 2X Teleconverter; ISO 800 1/125 f/5.6 800mm

Answer (score 14):

**Father, son and motorcycle**
[image: Father, son and motorcycle]
Pojanluoma, Finland
July 27, 2008

Panasonic DMC-FZ8

1/250 f/5, ISO 100, fixed lens 51.8 mm

Comment: What’s the Exif info on this picture I would really like to know. Great photo. Example: Shutter speed, Aperture, iso body, lens and what focal length did you shoot this. Thanks

Comment: 1/250 s, f/5, ISO 100, fixed lens 51.8 mm. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

## Sunset

Mother and daughter

[image: Sunset]

Nikon Z 6, AF-P NIKKOR 70-300 mm 1:4,5-5,6E ED VR at 70 mm, f/4.5, 1/40 s, ISO 100

Answer (score 11):

**Holding Hands**
[image]

A couple heading up the steps onto the Brooklyn Bridge at dusk on April 5, 2014.

Canon EOS 400D, 18-55mm kit lens @ 55mm, f/5.6, 1/60 second, ISO 400

Answer (score 11):

**Family**

Waiting for sunset on the cliff near Bovbjerg Lighthouse, Denmark, August 2021.

Nikon D3100, Helios 81N, 50mm, 1/640s, f/13, ISO 100.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

#### Weeeeee!

[image: Weeeeee!]

My friend spinning around with one of our friend's kid at a park.

Sony A7iii w/ 70-200 f2.8 Tamron at 70mm 1/200 f2.8 ISO 400

Comment: Just a suggestion, composing for movement can be problematic, but increasing the shutter speed + iso (or shutter only, then increase the exposure in post without burning the white) would help to get sharper edges and at the same time hopefully even less burned pixels due to the sun. Or perhaps try to reposition yourself to the direction the kid has. Otherwise it's great!

Comment: haha yes totally agree-- the moment caught me by surprise so I just held down the shutter and hoped for the best :)

Answer (score 7):

#### Couple on Tempelhof airfield

[image]

Berlin, Germany
September 2012

Camera and settings:

- Canon EOS 550D
- Some M42 lens with an adapter (no EXIF of the lens recorded)
- ISO 100
- 1/2000

Answer (score 6):

**The Clasping Hands**

[image]

A couple crossing Lafayette Street along 8th Street late in the evening.

Canon EOS 6D, 85mm, f/1.2, 1/1000 second, ISO 200

Comment: Was this at night? I noticed you are shooting wide open with 1/1000 ss actually if it was night your ss would be lower right? Where you in manual?

Comment: It was evening, a bit after 6pm in the middle of the summer.  The sunlight on the building in the background was reflecting off other buildings.  I was walking in sun and shade, so I think I had the camera set on time priority at 1/1000 second and the 200 ISO, letting the camera pick the aperture.

Comment: Hold on, are those dudes pants and boots the same connected material?? That's awesome.

Comment: @BruceWayne I think they're just tight fitting enough to look like it.  That's certainly not a style I could pull of like the dude in the photo!

Comment: Haha, yeah.  Though it does seem to me that the seam (...sorry) is [going down the pants, to the boot part as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1vc8.png). I need this clothing combo.  Either way, great photo.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yeah, the seams in both are lined up just right, and both are equally tight.  Close up, though, not quite...  Actually, going back to my original photo set from that afternoon, in another one that I never posted because it's slightly out of focus, at his right ankle there's a little skin visible between his pant leg and boot.

Answer (score 5):

## Father & son

[image]

A photo picturing father and son having fun at a landing place at lake Constance. It was taken on a warm spring day in May 2012.

Shot with a Sony Slt-A33 @ 200.0mm, f/6.3 1/320s, ISO 125. Several years ago I also shared this picture on [pixabay](https://pixabay.com/de/photos/steg-vater-und-sohn-sonnenuntergang-1286270/) in full res.

Answer (score 4):

**Uncle Steve**

My brother-in-law (Steve) with my daughter (Thea)

OMD E-10 Mk III
Panasonix Lumix 25mm prime at f/1.7, 1/1600 ISO-200

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Laugh on first sight**

[image]

Me and a beautiful l girl I've known for 2 days.
Vacation on a cabin.

Shot with a Fujifilm XT3000.

Immenstadt, Germany
07.08.2021

Comment: @Fenix, I took the freedom to soft-crop the photo to a square temporarily so people can scroll by easier, hope that's ok. The full picture is still available on click. Feel free to edit the post to include another crop to your liking.

Comment: @Saaru Thanks, I appreciate the effort! I had cropped the image before uploading, but it seems imgur defaulted to adding bars again. The submissions look a lot cleaner this way. :)

Answer (score 3):

### Homecoming Queen & Dad

A Homecoming Queen and her father share a moment during the singing of the school's Alma Mater immediately after the winner was announced and crowned at halftime of the Homecoming football game.

[image]

<sub>Canon EOS 7D Mark II + EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II @ 140mm. ISO 3200, f/3.5, 1/500.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

**Newlyweds in Central Park**

[image]

A newlywed couple sharing a moment in the Naumburg Bandshell in Central Park, New York after formalizing their relationship….  October 2014.  I don’t know them, I was just walking by…

Canon EOS 6D, 100-300mm zoom @ 180mm, f/5.6, 1/160 second, ISO 125